# How to fix the error caused: pub get failed(69)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-test

I'm having a problem to run the application for Flutter.

> pub get failed(69)

I've tried using `firebase_storage: any` and `firebase_storage: ^1.0.4`

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+2
  firebase_database: ^0.4.6
  firbase_storage: any
  firebase_core: any
  intl: ^0.15.7
  image_picker:



dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I expected the output to receive the exit code 0 but instead it tells me pub get failed (69)

Answer (score 5):

The main problem is network.
Sometimes "flutter pub get" is returning "exit code: 69" because of network problem.
You can check your network and you can change using VPN.

Comment: That's what it was. Connection was being blocked by the firewall.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to unwanted space in the below code

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+2
  firebase_database: ^0.4.6
  firbase_storage: any
  firebase_core: any
  intl: ^0.15.7
  image_picker:
```

You can use [YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/) validator to check the issue in the yaml file.

Try once like this:

```yaml
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+2
  firebase_database: ^0.4.6
  firbase_storage: any
  firebase_core: any
  intl: ^0.15.7
  image_picker:



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Delete 'pubspec.lock' file
2. Restart your PC.
3. Write in Terminal

> flutter pub get

Answer (score -2):

Check the environment variables whether the directory in which you try to create is mentioned in the path