# pub get failed/exit code: 69

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-doctor

I just downloaded and installed flutter SDK(archive).
when I run the "flutter doctor" command on my mac m1 terminal I receive this error. pub get failed/exit code: 69
[image]

thank you for guiding me.

"flutter doctor" command not work.

Comment: add the error in text form its hard to read and making pain in the eye.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the error caused: pub get failed(69)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800642/how-to-fix-the-error-caused-pub-get-failed69)

Answer (score 3):

if you are in Iran, China or Afghanistan try using VPN and make sure your command line (CMD,Terminal) has access to internet via proxy, then run below commands on the project folder, lets say your project folder is e:\flutterProjects\project_one then run these commands:

flutter packages get

flutter packages upgrade

flutter pub outdated

and who says that US Sanctions does not take peoples freedom they are just for the idiot governors

Answer (score 1):

try running `flutter config --clear-features`
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when adding a package with a **mistaken version**!
For example, the latest version of the `path_provider` package, for now, is `^2.0.14`, if you mistakenly add e.g `4.0.1` you'll face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Delete pubspec.lock file >> restart your device, then Pub get

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that you have been blocked from using this feature due to region restrictions, try using vpn app that uses split tunneling method in order to use vpn in your apps not only in browser.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)